# Are "I have a dollar note" and "I have a one-dollar note" the same?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

The Oxford dictionary says "**[a 10-dollar bill/note](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bill_1?q=bill)**", so I guess we can say "**a 1-dollar bill/note**"

And The Oxford dictionary also says "[a dollar coin](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/coin_1?q=coin)"

So I guess we can also say "**a dollar bill/note**".

Are "**I have a dollar note**" and "**I have a one-dollar note**" the same?

Comment: In Britian, I have a pound coin, and I have a one pound coin, would be the same

Comment: You should make that your answer, James. It answers the question pretty comprehensively.

Comment: In US English "a dollar bill" and "a one-dollar bill" are both acceptable. The former might place more emphasis on the physical currency and the latter on the monetary value, but the difference is so subtle as to be almost not there at all.

Comment: Do Americans still have dollar bills? We stopped printing pound notes in the UK back in 1984, so I assume they ceased to be legal tender fairly soon after that.

Comment: In the United States, paper $1 bills are still printed, https://www.usa.gov/currency, but it takes **ten** of them to purchase a dozen eggs, in some areas. *sigh*